# not able to update expo-font from 9.1.0 to 9.2.1 in a vanilla react-native

Tags: react-native, fonts, expo

I'm trying to use `yarn upgrade-interactive` to update expo-font from `9.1.0` to `9.2.1` in a vanilla react-native project.

```
? Choose which packages to update. 
 dependencies
   name       range   from      to     url
❯◉ expo-font  ^9.1.0  9.1.0  ❯  9.2.1  https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk
```

After the update is done I get the following working when running the app and it fails to load specific fonts.

```
 WARN     Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 5):
Error: There is no FontManager in module registry. Are you sure all the dependencies of expo-font are installed and linked?
Error: There is no FontManager in module registry. Are you sure all the dependencies of expo-font are installed and linked?
    at promiseMethodWrapper (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2176:45)
    at anonymous (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:167493:40)
    at loadSingleFontAsync$ (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:168033:80)
    at call (native)
    at tryCatch (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:24976:23)
    at invoke (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25149:32)
    at anonymous (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25019:30)
    at call (native)
    at tryCatch (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:24976:23)
    at invoke (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25049:30)
    at anonymous (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:25059:21)
    at tryCallOne (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:27064:16)
    at anonymous (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:27165:27)
    at apply (native)
    at anonymous (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:30714:26)
    at _callTimer (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:30602:17)
    at _callImmediatesPass (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:30641:17)
    at callImmediates (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:30858:33)
    at __callImmediates (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2655:35)
    at anonymous (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2441:34)
    at __guard (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2638:15)
    at flushedQueue (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2440:21)
    at invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false:2433:33)
```

Answer (score 1):

What I had to to to fix this was:

Update react-native-unimodues from 0.13.3 to 0.14.5 with the following command

```
yarn add react-native-unimodules
```

For more info, https://docs.expo.io/bare/installing-unimodules/ but my project was already wired with unimodule but yarn add command updated the version number.

This allowed for yarn to resolve the expo-font to 9.2.1. I was able to see this in `yarn.lock`

I changed in `package.json` the version by hand to

```
"expo-font": "^9.2.1",
```